# Persistent List with constexpr and pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list in C++, functional and persistent. Before looking into sample implementations, I tried to come up with my own as an exercise.

I came up with two versions:

1. One is using pointers as is customary in C++. I am trying to set up an interface that respects structural sharing.
2. The other one is using full-`constexpr`. It is basically a compile-time list, if you do not use `operator<<`.

To begin, the complete code is so long so I am going to start with a link to `Compiler Explorer` that contains all of the code. [Here is the code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgAYB2ACwBOAKyCATAGZhsucIAcpAFZdSrZrVDIApBIBCe/aQDOqAK7FkHAOR6peWslbmsAah1SAwnlQmCxJjMALae2Dq8AIL2js6umB7eBACeAA6YAPoBzIQmYRHRUf7MBHjIbiZ4AF6ZBG5EBGwZbKyoLASY6IkAIm68noZRBbQhmCapzNZuyAioqSYe/IORHcGpGh2JXinpI8EJACr5Uc7MJgusjgDWnRmX/ovLqeYARpfIIAVu327mlVpuABqbHMmAOaQSnl6Rykyx%2BHii8NW6xKkKSEL2CWBLjBEOOkXh/mI5mQdXuBAytAwmB0Sy%2B8J%2B2NB4PSbgAbmwBvSGW5yZTqW4AFS0TAADwIXMRPIRBOlaFoDyZuNZCCC6AgAEppnQHrS4dL4YECJZaOzObDuQzad1LfD5Q8%2BVT3ILGnhWJrtQq6nrbdKjSa3CLxZLZTzrb7vhHeXh/PznV5WiKIPayTGKU7MIK3KgCKriBqfVKDd88FQIDm8z0oYHzKxWKkAgWi8XDZhjcRTbRa/WAiGW5Hmwao/DHdSs4ETLXvVJeiKAO7R2MZvv9hpNFptVFdIzVyo1VBl0dYTxeJUsmlSbAFi2Dv1jKcAWjCHNYPWzucwxCfl5fK5bE8fMIg2nXoEzoTByw/L8gLFAhr31f82wDADWAlG9QytfgbVvAcMPhKhiDwTBaC6fx0BAEA/ACIJQgkAA2bN0mIEoSBPE8IDIiiqMCEI9AYolSGHfthM9B00zjC9TxBZUL2wIVkDwAs6RwhlS2TPAqxnGs6wbfNCzw/siS2E8PAkCQdFELxaD0cz0JEn5/Q7Cpezs/twxUwkAmM7xpjwb9sFVZh1S1NifJs0yJG8rxfP8113XgoTvkc00iT/TDsIw8NXNw%2BE/kcYA3C8HUCAAGTTABJDpmKIYg3xTRd02pE8zzxS9BTSvKATK/xKs/FjaurI9JJa9Iwna7LnJKMpRLqPdakDakMjmt85oPCAhua6TzzCBLm0tS5aBudA7jTD0QAyQL0D1LsdN7LDSDcZhKUwOcMjQVJkj1Kg2BMGksP0g0LrVN8bp7Yg0qyhCZRHa5bnJZNiujQ64bTPj3zzJSofhNSgaCtwwDAatQd0zHErcXH0H84CQe7XS0oNLB2E2Cn6Z%2BdyDO%2BCmadu8GJvhKMuerCn/LApMK0/bgKd2jnHue173uSN8AlBVnvk4lALGnLwTJshW3BjNwEGYVJdnyiyrJsiH/qGZsAD8DqOk7/E1S0AelHHLvxwmtOJry%2BLRgmnvnN65mSUmPJ%2BdW0HMLWdbMrwWny%2BpVTcLAiRJGrzesszVYZYWYPFbmwdz%2BFGbbBIWb5tmsMwVhfqjN2W26gheuqkhpksQJ6DfSuselOcEDdCDkE74i6gJonacbRuRKjzWooihO6yTj9U7GZXSVYyzs9svum4qqr%2BsDWC6tH%2Bgqdgku5TPggL8Lyeeavnky82EfiC7tC9%2BLN%2BP5By%2Bq7DNbGW7N%2BZAMtMwGOqA3CpECLsdUBwzSsC1CmGe8Jm6tyPsHDMf8FwbW8CNWSuc1ysGaHWTcHRtwGF3NUTAa08FSRxNtS80sDRYOpP5F8b5fwAOPq9DMd8QLk0urnZKSNHbkmui9CSkNXZgObBAoghs1QenqqghySEnL50vJdF2E12aWiKl6dBh8ar1ByPFGajwoyiK0dgOKuioYgLZs2F4qBUCvhjBkTAawUgqMRqgmxnsoQP2LrCZxmUgEwLwByDonxmwOxRs7YxfVTEvEwMARwWoQBCOUWkjJtANQPSDlIhWX0fp/QyqAww/09HNmSW3WqvdLSuPcbLYOpT0IyL2lEZEGw0TbAxKMNwMJwhFAIORSiRIaJozmCk1i3h2Lq24tM%2BizkyCWIScdCR3gRloyQTPNSrBuCeO8Q2ZImpw4yyMqFaKltt6Wx4aI1KeigGeQGgsnyRydEhQ%2BbcsyEUF5HPsSw9R7YUouWWPouRkRHB1GCDkWgLshhLHCXaRGMw5gmAopsp2aEfD0DCLyVgaVDlHJOT485GomxXPGRRaOscwpmWwBShqE97k51qRheqCioF1kioNI5MDMBwIgHREF3xuWQKJVIN8fLuBCpFaIcVlieVEsELK1gUh5WwOIuqQQyrJWKLrKIDVghtXCt1RAKQBrEaqrrAxAVohzUiokDar0j0pV1n4BquizrLWcGlpaOeMdAWsH4GlYNDLor2u4MCtK9UMXzGxbDLZqNvCwsJawUpSx7VdIwpGwFHTHHNjUurTxJhRgZDZCeLAzgdgQTrIUtedaITrTDdeK8UYC03IigcHMbBHpkPaJ0Nw%2BxggkEVgbcKPbiGkNaMO7cvyAUvGSB0PI7Ld6u2bN2pdNkGA0OzFQfW3cYzZOnUu1aZZYU/O1oy/lG6I20o1iGnte6D0HgatI9NBLLz6yxRFMmkYl2JqxSAHF2z8VoWwBRDMS0D2AYXtOh9nLrQ2EKawEANhRA2FILQTDvAcOoEw9rKhBgKgWCsJCaQnAcMEHw2h0gEAkBoCwLgQgJByCUBoPQJgbAOA8AECIcQ0h5ByCUKoCQ6hNDaB3AYUwFHrCYZiE4Fw7gTy%2BCmbxS8BRlNxDU%2BidIWRmK5HxMMUY4xJgJBA1Ynppy%2BlbHrZiNw2BOAPUc0M7AtlRmRHTqSaBOQBrKUKFy4qYoYH%2BbwMQM6b1mDgyWC5n0/17rk2QOgOL%2BhPOJZtMl05KQ9TKwqbI6pGVLQpjC7VCYkWEbupc6ZOiLB1n1U83V1LelmznQa3qTryW3ppa631nLFKyl10K3tOk0K0VenKx6xRDW/FejUUlDRpoYu80cRNn4ZXRThdVa1%2Bb/hFtuBsa1q2JXmwESIiRZyEzlm8VWbMhpNyOJPtu7RfiARBIR3shF3mXgXMPUy7%2B1IlyDRqVSNwXLYcyZPIhV2v2S7wdzZvXHfl/ye2I7Sw46xy21mnZ082JrnAUuxfjYjZrvW1vNLca%2BSHIY80FF6aiBzgz9jOdc/UFnCRAfea2%2BFlpr4Hv9WCTOarDxKu/f%2B85rzaNUjs/quLk8kvucy9dTpoLrYwVuAgLL7gSPNK9FSBIXXsWLl1bRtrnge2fk2i0ob3XmOqV0%2BhYzzYJ53Os4ABJqjc5z4Z5j8SnHOA1Gezw3hlDicFyb/hpvww1CAVIWWHq06WAVpxkZxtnZC1N7btV4Ze7xggB6BxzH1GpfCePepC/1GtEnobSxvojbT1YjbErQs55m1AhVlr89dAQMg4qepoZ3k1xBnvD1a2oVbcD/ISwq8J5qetzPUeOjt9Vd8yxh3RGI5N8q/RBO287alcCjf6vh8BggxP%2Bt2v7dRY1Mb2/hSEPP0wC29I1%2Brc34ufib7mF9AY9v/fpqJ9jLCJP/pqJ/mXj/tXDbovvjhhPzn%2Bl4hSvtt6KfjyKIrTi8kvj8BdrqtdlxJpm9oxHMr9osi9oQWjAJE/lATDAdt4GPn7m6JmiDtKNckuoKrnGwben8uZMhl/DDpTmNtgd8FEjEhwJaArvQd7owcSkDmlAgZgZCgvnAS7v0u7ocPiJ1AVOBmmLKmml4AcEXvkJ0sipnrCqOgikitEGgTNNNiBsmsjKmnQZBpmpwHTvvtnofkavylpKwDwF3iRKKm6tHqvp6jKoNEbgEeqEqqTp4bVHauqoNFqlERAPqgMEPq3nER3ryCaoNGaikdaukaVgfvEZ6g6r4U6ikarmEsUVkXat6oNL6ikQGkUTbFniEV4bynrINPwLGuYljtuk%2BvSoCqII%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%2BAKgmlmluAWnjJWlal2kOlHEcCurfFrFukMkelek%2Bl%2BkBluBBla6hntwnEPSRlZlIkxmurxk2mJkEYXFXGKncD8AKCyC8B0RCD8CcASC8CcDomrG/G7lbE7FAlqCgnPnOk2CnFgWEaAmkDQVoaFJtnECVB0AgCCBAA%3D%3D%3D). There, "C++ Source 1" contains the code for pointer based implementation. "C++ Source 2" contains more functional implementation. You can find respective compiler outputs on the right pane.

First one is the pointer-based version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

static size_t total_allocated = 0;

namespace chops {
template <typename T>
class linked_list {
public:
    using ValueType = T;

    template <typename ValueType>
    struct list_node{
        ValueType val;
        list_node *next;

    const ValueType head() const {
        return val;
    }
    const list_node *tail() const {
        return next;
    }

    list_node *Clone(const list_node* other){
        if(other == nullptr)
            return nullptr;


        list_node* result = new list_node;
        total_allocated += sizeof(list_node<ValueType>);
        result->val = other->val;
        result->next = Clone(other->next);
        return result;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                             const list_node<ValueType> *ci){
        if(ci == nullptr){
            str << "\n";
            return str;
        }
        str << ci->head() << " " << ci->tail();
        return str;
    }
    };

    using ConstListIterator = const list_node<ValueType>*;
    using ListIterator = list_node<ValueType>*;
    static const size_t node_size = sizeof(list_node<ValueType>);

    linked_list() :_head{nullptr}, a_new_copy{false}{
        _head = nullptr;
    };

    linked_list(const linked_list& other){
        if(_head != nullptr){
            _head->next = nullptr;
            delete _head;
        }
        _head = nullptr;

        _head = _head->Clone(other._head);
        a_new_copy = true;
        std::cout << "copy is happening\n";
    }

    ~linked_list()
    {
        if(_head != nullptr && !a_new_copy){
            std::cout << "Calling the destructor\n";
            _head->next = nullptr;
            delete _head;
        }else
        {
            ListIterator current = _head;
            while(current != nullptr){
                std::cout << "Calling the destructor\n";
                ListIterator next = current->next;
                current->next = nullptr;
                delete current;
                current = next;
            }
        }
    }

    auto prepend(T val) const{
        ListIterator new_node = new list_node<ValueType>;
        total_allocated += sizeof(list_node<ValueType>);
        new_node->val = val;
        new_node->next = _head;
        return linked_list{new_node};
    }

    auto head() const {
        return _head->head();
    }

    ConstListIterator tail() const {
        return _head->tail();
    }

    bool is_empty() const {
    return _head == nullptr;   
    }

    private:
    linked_list(ListIterator begin) : _head(begin), a_new_copy{false}
    {};

    ListIterator _head;
        bool a_new_copy;
    };

    template <typename T>
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const linked_list<T>& l){
        if(l.is_empty()){
            str << "\n";
            return str;
        }
        str << l.head() << " " << l.tail();
        return str;
    }

}

int main()
{   
    const chops::linked_list<int> ll;
    if(ll.is_empty())
        std::cout << "Empty list!\n";

    const auto ll2 = ll.prepend(6);
    const auto ll3 = ll2.prepend(5);
    const auto ll4 = ll3.prepend(4);
    const auto ll5 = ll4.prepend(3);
    const auto ll6 = ll5.prepend(2);
    const auto ll7 = ll6.prepend(1);

    std::cout << ll7;
    std::cout << ll6.tail();
    const chops::linked_list<int> lcopy{ll6};
    std::cout << lcopy;

    if(std::is_same_v<decltype(ll), decltype(ll7)>)
        std::cout << "Total allocated memory is " << total_allocated << " bytes\n";

    std::cout << "Size of int is: " << sizeof(int) << " \n";
    std::cout << "Size of list_node<int> is: "
              << chops::linked_list<int>::node_size 
              << " \n";

}
```

And, here is the `constexpr` version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace chops {
template <typename E1, typename E2>
struct pair {

    constexpr pair() :_car{E1{}}, _cdr{E2{}}, empty{true}
    {}

    constexpr pair(const E1 &car, const E2 &cdr)
    :_car{car}, _cdr{cdr}, empty{false}
    {}

    constexpr auto car() const{
        return _car;
    }

    constexpr auto cdr() const{
        return _cdr;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                                    pair<E1, E2> p){
        if(p.empty)
            return str;
        str << p.car() << " " << p.cdr();
        return str;
    }

    const E1 _car;
    const E2 _cdr;
    bool empty;
};

template <typename E1, typename E2>
constexpr bool operator==(const pair<E1, E2>& p1, const pair<E1, E2>& p2)
{
    return (p1.car() == p2.car()) && (p1.cdr() == p2.cdr());
}

template <typename Head, typename Tail>
class list{
    public:

    constexpr list():p{}, empty{true}
    {}

    constexpr list(Head h, Tail t)
    :p{h, t}, empty{false}
    {}

    constexpr auto prepend(Head h) const{ 
        return list<Head, decltype(p)>{h, p};
    }

    constexpr auto head() const {
        return p.car();
    }

    constexpr auto tail() const {
        return list<decltype(p.cdr().car()),
                    decltype(p.cdr().cdr())>
                    {p.cdr().car(),
                     p.cdr().cdr()
                    };
    }

    bool is_empty() const {
        return empty;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str,
                                    list<Head, Tail> l){
        str << l.p;
        str << "\n";
        return str;
    }

    private:
    pair<Head, Tail> p;
    bool empty;
};

template <typename T>
using linked_list = list<T, T>;

}

int main()
{
    constexpr chops::linked_list<int> l1;
    constexpr auto l2 = l1.prepend(6);
    constexpr auto l3 = l2.prepend(5);
    constexpr auto l4 = l3.prepend(4); 
    constexpr auto l5 = l4.prepend(3); 
    constexpr auto l6 = l5.prepend(2); 
    constexpr auto l7 = l6.prepend(1); 

    constexpr auto lcopy = l7.tail();
    std::cout << l5;
    std::cout << l4.tail();
    std::cout << lcopy;
}
```

I think these are working somewhat correctly but I need to ask couple of questions.

1. Are there any errors that I am missing? How would you improve this code, in general terms?
2. Why is the pointer-based implementation generating so much longer assembly, assuming this indicates a slower code. They are doing pretty-much the same thing but compile-time version is much faster. Look at the next question for further points.
3. Is my second implementation truly constexpr? I can see a compile-time version can be faster, since computation happens at compile-time. But in the sample, I am not putting `constexpr` in my declarations. I can construct those lists in main as `constexpr` as well. For example, I can do this, adding `constexpr`:

   ```
   constexpr chops::linked_list<int> l1;
   constexpr auto l2 = l1.prepend(6);
   constexpr auto l3 = l2.prepend(5);
   constexpr auto l4 = l3.prepend(4); 
   constexpr auto l5 = l4.prepend(3); 
   constexpr auto l6 = l5.prepend(2); 
   constexpr auto l7 = l6.prepend(1); 

   constexpr auto lcopy = l7.tail();
   std::cout << l5;
   std::cout << l4.tail();
   std::cout << lcopy;
   ```

   and if I comment out the I/O part, this generates nearly no-code at all which is expected right, assuming all the computation happens at compile-time?
4. My compile-time version is more like `lisp` const-lists. They are made out of `pair`s which also lives in `chops` namespace. So tail of a list is just another nested-pair. This complicates things a-little bit. I had to invent an empty `pair`. If you think as a mathematical abstraction, an empty pair might not be a good idea. But pointer-based version can just use `nullptr` to indicate empty list. The other problem with compile-time version is that, I wrapped `list` into a `linked_list` through a variable template. But in reality, every `list` has a different type. After you `prepend`, you get a new `list` and it's type is not the same as input `list`. Types in the compile-time version contains all the structure of the list. For example type of `(1 2 3)` is
   `list<int, pair<int, int>>`. Would this pose a disadvantage in terms of generic usage? Is it better if all had the type `List<T>`?
5. What should be the copy-semantics for a purely functional list? Right now, I am treating every copy as if a new world of lists created, separate from the previous list worlds. Is there any mistakes here? My destructor is just deleting the prepended node, unless it is the beginning of a new copy. You can check this out in the code, in the pointer-based version. Compile-time version has no destructor or copy constructor. It is all value-semantics. Which would you prefer?
6. How would you implement multithreading and `fmap`-like facility in the compile-time version?
7. Would move-semantics help the performance of the pointer-based version?
8. What are the code-smells you can point out?
9. Is the heavy use of recursion problematic here?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question.](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308) Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed because you ask a review of two very different pieces of code. They aren't two different implementations of the same concept. I believe you should ask about one or the other, but not both. About the second kind of `list`, there is no difference between a pair and a list, so it isn't really useful to write two different classes. `List`s in functional or functional-friendly languages are algebraic types (in this instance either `nil` or a `cons`) we don't really have in C++, hence the weird empty pair.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a [tag:comparative-review] (as in "which of these should I use?")?  If not, it might be better as two questions.

Comment: @papagaga I probably did something wrong there, I thought about it. But, performance questions and C++ type system related questions made me believe that it is better if i gave a sample implementation of both.